# CMOS technology that works above 300 °C

Tags: integrated-circuit, asic, chip-design

I need technology in which the IC will work at temperatures above 300 °C. For example, [Fraunhofer](https://www.ims.fraunhofer.de) makes chips at this temperature using Tungsten interconnect.
Do foundries like TSMC or Globalfoundries have similar technology for fabricating high-temperature chips?

I'm looking for a chip like this. Can it be made with conventional foundries such as TSMC or GF ...? 
[High temperature SOI CMOS technology and circuit realization for applications up to 300°C](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7168845)

I need technology like this: 
[**High Temperature Electronics**](https://www.ims.fraunhofer.de/en/Business_Units_and_Core_Competencies/High_Temperature_Electronics.html)

Comment: Why must the IC work at temperatures above 300 C? Why can't you place the IC somewhere else or shield it from heat?

Comment: IC is located next to a strong source of heat and cannot be shielded.

Comment: Consider fluidics, that works well at high temperature

Comment: *Do foundries like TSMC or Globalfoundries have similar technology for fabricating high-temperature chips?* I would say that they don't but I could be wrong. This high temperature stuff looks to me like it is still in the research phase (Fraunhofer is a research institute not a commercial foundry like TSMC and GF).

Comment: or wait till  carbon nanotube IC's come out. Arhennius Law prevails. 200'C works for a short time.. get a chiller. read ... IEEE  TRANSACTIONS  ON  COMPONENTS,  HYBRIDS,  AND  MANUFACTURING  TECHNOLOGY,  VOL.  16, NO.  7,  NOVEMBER  1993  159
2OO'C for 72 hrs Operation  of  Semiconductor Power Devices
R.  Wayne Johnson,  Member,  ZEEE,  James  R.  Bromstead, and  G.  Bennett  Weir

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Actually, some Fraunhofers do have commercial production.  HHI does it, if I remember correctly.

Comment: any reason not to place the IC away from the source? you mention an ADC in you other comment - what kind of signal should the ADC measure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honeywell SRAM [HT6256](https://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/165352/HONEYWELL/HT6256.html).

> The RAM provides guaranteed performance over the full
> -55 to +225°C temperature range. Typically, parts will operate up to +300°C for a year, with derated performance.

But I feel that this technology protected by many NDAs.

The "*[Prolonged 500 °C Operation of 100+ Transistor Silicon Carbide
Integrated Circuits](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20180002167/downloads/20180002167.pdf)*" article tells that:

> This report describes more than 5000 hours of successful 500 °C
> operation of semiconductor integrated circuits (ICs) with more than
> 100 transistors.

"*Ozark Integrated Circuits*" [reports](https://www.ozarkic.com/our-services/high-temperature/) that they can produce 600°C ICs with SiC transistors on aluminium substrate.

Also you may look at the "*[Honeywell's HTMOS™ High Temperature Electronics](https://aerospace.honeywell.com/content/dam/aero/en-us/documents/learn/products/microelectronics/technical-articles/NewParadigmInElectronicsDeepDrillingFromAmericanOilAndGasReporter2005.pdf)*" article and the "*[Geothermal Technologies Program 2010](https://www.energy.gov/sites/prod/files/2014/02/f7/high_tilak_electronics_platform.pdf)*" article.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from the link below:

> The XI10 series is a partly depleted SOI high voltage technology. It is ideally suited for automotive and industrial applications operating at high temperatures up to 225 °C.

https://www.xfab.com/technology/soi/10-um-xi10/

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. Unfortunately this doesn't answer the original question, where the OP wanted to know about "*technology in which the IC will work at temperatures above 300 °C*". The technology described on your linked page "only" goes up to 225 °C.